# tab material ui dont accept div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using Material UI tabs on my site, but I can't use divs inside the tabpanel, only text-related labels and divs. But a common div with "width", "height", "background" are even accepted, but a pop out appears with the following message "Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error%22)

My code (I'm using react with styled components):

```
import {
    Content,
    DefenseGroup,
    PartsRow,
    Defense,
    DefenseCard,
    InputDefense,
    ModBox,
    BoxRow,
    GropuArmorAndPenalty,
    PenaltyAndArmorText,
    Stats,
    PenaltyAndArmor,
    ModBoxGroup,
    EXP,
    EXPInput,
  } from "./styles";
  import { CheckSkills, InputSkills, SkillsText } from "../Skills/styles";
  import { Title } from "../../styles/global";
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import * as React from "react";
  import PropTypes from "prop-types";
  import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
  import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
  import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
  import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
  import styled from "styled-components";
  
  
  function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  
    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Box sx={{ p: 0}}>
            <Typography>{children}</Typography>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };
  
  function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }
  
  export default function DefenseMultipliers() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  
    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    };
  
    const inputs = [
      { width: "100px" },
      { width: "90px" },
      { width: "80px" },
      { width: "30px" },
    ];
  
    const inputs2 = [
      { width: "70%" },
      { width: "100%" },
      { width: "70%" },
      { width: "100%" },
    ];
  
    return (
      <Content>
        <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              aria-label="basic tabs example"
            >
              <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
              <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
              <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
            <DefenseGroup>
              <PartsRow>
                <Defense>
                  <DefenseCard>
                    <Title>Defesa</Title>
                    <InputDefense
                      type={"number"}
                      disabled
                      top={"10px"}
                      border={"none"}
                      placeholder={"10"}
                    ></InputDefense>
                  </DefenseCard>
                  <InputDefense
                    borderRadius={"50%"}
                    disabled
                    left={"-10px"}
                    placeholder={"=10"}
                  ></InputDefense>
                </Defense>
                <ModBox>
                  <ModBoxGroup>
                    <BoxRow width={"100%"}>
                      <CheckSkills type={"checkbox"}></CheckSkills>
                      <SkillsText fontSize={"10px"}>
                        Modificador de Des
                      </SkillsText>
                      <SkillsText fontSize={"10px"}>Bônus de Armadura</SkillsText>
                      <SkillsText fontSize={"10px"}>Bônus de Escudo</SkillsText>
                      <SkillsText fontSize={"10px"}>Outros</SkillsText>
                    </BoxRow>
                    <BoxRow width={"92%"}>
                      {inputs.map((res) => {
                        return (
                          <InputSkills
                            width={res.width}
                            height={"15px"}
                            placeholder={"0"}
                          ></InputSkills>
                        );
                      })}
                    </BoxRow>
                  </ModBoxGroup>
                  <BoxRow width={"100%"}>
                    <SkillsText>Penalidade de Armadura</SkillsText>
                    <InputSkills
                      width={"48%"}
                      height={"15px"}
                      placeholder={"0"}
                    ></InputSkills>
                  </BoxRow>
                </ModBox>
              </PartsRow>
              <GropuArmorAndPenalty>
                <PenaltyAndArmor width={"60%"}>
                  <Title>ARMADURA & DEFESA</Title>
                  <InputSkills
                    width={"90%"}
                    height={"15px"}
                    placeholder={"0"}
                  ></InputSkills>
                  <InputSkills
                    width={"90%"}
                    height={"15px"}
                    placeholder={"0"}
                  ></InputSkills>
                </PenaltyAndArmor>
                Space
                <PenaltyAndArmor width={"40%"}>
                  <PenaltyAndArmorText>
                    <SkillsText>Defesa</SkillsText>
                    <SkillsText>Penalidade</SkillsText>
                  </PenaltyAndArmorText>
                  <Stats>
                    {inputs2.map((res) => {
                      return (
                        <InputSkills
                          width={res.width}
                          height={"15px"}
                          placeholder={"0"}
                        ></InputSkills>
                      );
                    })}
                  </Stats>
                </PenaltyAndArmor>
              </GropuArmorAndPenalty>
              <EXP>
                <Title>PONTOS DE EXPERIÊNCIA</Title>
                <EXPInput type={"number"} placeholder={"Xp"}></EXPInput>
              </EXP>
            </DefenseGroup>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
            <div></div>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
            Item Three
          </TabPanel>
        </Box>
      </Content>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TabPanel: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692652/tabpanel-warning-validatedomnesting-div-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant)

Comment: quoting: remove the <Typography> component you have upper in the tree and put it inside the children; Typography renders its children inside a <p> tag which causes this error

Comment: Try see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870995/18337391 It is quite similar.